# putting a variable into a css button's href attribute

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to affect a variable containing  url to a css button's href attribute i tried location.href but it didn't work .

here's my button description :

```
             <div>
          <p><a id="gameNextLevel" class="button"  href="">Next</a></p>
      </div>
```

Here's my JSF related code :

```
            var uiNextLevel = $("gameNextLevel");
            matchingGame.savingObject.currentLevel="game6.html";

                uiNextLevel.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                                // location.href = "login.html";
                 location.href =  matchingGame.savingObject.currentLevel;  

                });
```

Any idea please , Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the hash `#` in the selector, which means `id`

```
var uiNextLevel = $("#gameNextLevel");
```

also, for "dead links", use a hash `#` also in the `href`.

```
<a id="gameNextLevel" class="button"  href="#">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 uiNextLevel.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $(this).attr("href") =  matchingGame.savingObject.currentLevel;  

                });
```